# Лагает при вхождении в трубу

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

В общем, у меня есть труба, с простенькой текстурой, её размер (1,50,1), не большой, если в неё не заходить то все хорошо, а если зайти начинает фризить (при чем только с телефона), что можно сделать?

Телефон 2018 года, хороший, пубг на средний идет хорошо.

Текстура следующая: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
загрузка видеокарты: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шейдер использую следующий: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но даже с стандартной (белой) фризы.

Сцена это просто шарик вкатываеться в трубу, по началу он просто котиться по кубу, на котором находиться труба.

Полный профайлер [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тестовый проект: https://dropmefiles.com/fgwIb

Comment: Что значит "простенькая" текстура? Сложных текстур не бывает. Что значит "фризить" только с телефона? На пк вообще никаких изменений в профайлере? Какой шейдер висит на трубе? Шейдер opaque или работает с прозрачностью? Как устроена сцена? Дополните вопрос.

Comment: Почему Вы привели только данные профайлера по рендеру? Узкое место запросто может быть в чем-то другом. В коллизиях, например, или каком-то фрагменте кода в Update, FixedUpdate или корутине...

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский так лагает только при вхождении, апдейты вообще не вызываються, точнее два апдейта имеют в начале return, даже сцена с отключенными объектами и только кубом и трубой, все равно лагает, на трубе даже коллайдера нет

Comment: Ну для начала телефоны не очень дружат с transparent шейдерами. Добавьте **весь** профайлер, ваши догадки о его бесполезности ложны.

Comment: Кстати текстура крайне не оптимизированная, такого эффекта проще добиться через тайлинг, что сократит затраты как минимум видеопамяти == оперативной памяти на телефоне.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker текстура была тестовая, я же говорю, даже при стандартным материалом с стандартным шейдером фризит на телефоне.

Comment: Я сказал, что ключевая проблема может крыться в transparent шейдере, текстура - это "так", в довесок. Вас не удивляют пики в профайлере с 1ms до 4ms?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker так я говорю, даже с шейдером без transparent'a лагает

Comment: Значит нужно смотреть полный дебаг всей отрисовки и сравнивать фреймы в профайлере, пальцем в небо тут сложно угадать, игры - слишком сложный для такого дебага процесс.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker создал элементарную сцену, которая на телефона работает точно так же как и в моей игре, при вхождени в трубу (в данном случае появления) игра начинает идти как-то не плавно, это можно увидить используя слайдер - https://youtu.be/jh0hVNBOPyQ , видио с телефона не вижу смысла предоставлять, т.к. сама сьёмка уже не будет выдавать той картины которая есть на самом делел. Проект прикрепил.